# Indirect formula for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to learn how to do Conditional Formatting using the Indirect Formula so it will work across two tabs in the same spreadsheet.
I have a Calendar in Sheet1 and I would like the cells on this calendar change colour depending on the values in Sheet2.

My Calendar For January in Sheet1 has the following range:

```
B8 to H8       1st to 7th 
B9 to H9       8th to 14th    
B10 to H10     15th to 21st
B11 to H11     22nd to 28th
B12 to D11     29th to 31st
```

I would like the cells to remain white on the calendar if the cells in Sheet2 are negative and change to yellow if the cells in Sheet2 are Zero and change to red if it's a positive.

The cells in Sheet2 that the Calendar reads are:

I95 to N95      1st to 7th
9P95 to V95      8th to 14th
W95 to AC95      15th to 21st
AD95 to AJ95      22nd to 28th
AK95 to AM95      29th to 31st

So, for example, the Cell in Sheet2 I95 is -1 then the Cell B8 in Sheet1 will remain white, if I95=0 then the cell B8 in Sheet1 will turn Yellow and if greater than 0 B8 in Sheet1 will turn Red.

I assume this can be done using a range rather than have to repeat it 31 times just for January.